# Make supervisor ignore js updates in public directory

Tags: node.js, node-supervisor

I have a node app which has a /public subdirectory that has just static files in it (js, css, html, etc) along with scss files which need to be compiled

I am running my app by typing

```
sudo supervisor -n error -e js,json,scss,jade -p 1000 app
```

which makes it so whenever files with those extensions change within my root project directory the server will restart.

The problem is that js files under public shouldn't cause a restart. Is there a way to ignore a file time in a specific directory? Or if not, is there a way to just ignore a directory (and I will switch supervisor calls when I am working with scss).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quite simpy:
`supervisor -i /public` will ignore anything in the public directory.

More info at: https://github.com/petruisfan/node-supervisor

Comment: -i|--ignore <ignoreItems>
    A comma-delimited list of folders to ignore for changes.
    No default